# How to insert value in SQL string when using SET @sql

Tags: sql-server

Issue: I want to add "N/A" into my @SQL SELECT

Query: Can I add 'know' values or does I need to declare them and add as per the tableName?

Test: I have tried:

' + 'N/A' + '
and
' + "N/A" + '

Notes: If I remove the N/A line of code it works.

Error: Invalid column name 'N/A'.

Code:

```
USE [DB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spExcelIntoTable]    Script Date: 01/10/2015 13:27:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spExcelIntoTable]
(
    @tableName          NVARCHAR(256)     
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT a.ID AS ID,  
a.UPRN,p.BuildingNo,
p.Street,p.Postcode ,
a.ItemRef,a.SurveyDate ,
a.OverallRiskCategory ,
a.SurveyorsComments 

INTO  TEMP_' + @tableName + '

FROM TblAsbestos 

AS a JOIN TblProperty 
As p on a.UPRN = p.UPRN
WHERE a.OverallRiskCategory <> "N/A"
ORDER BY a.OverallRiskCategory'

EXEC (@sql)

END
GO
```

Comment: or have a single temp table with a column identifier for the scope of whatever your doing ...

Comment: You should at the very least wrap your variable in QUOTENAME to help prevent sql injection.

Comment: QUOTENAME? @SeanLange I'd like to avoid injection!

Comment: You should lookup these things in BOL (Books online). It is the documentation for the DBMS you are using. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx Here is how you use it in here. INTO ' + QUOTENAME('TEMP_' + @tableName) + '
FROM TblAsbestos'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic sql code use double `'`:

```
WHERE a.OverallRiskCategory <> ''N/A''
```

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes are object identifiers in SQL Server you need to use two single quotes to use string leteral.

At the moment sql server is treating "N/A" as a column name  `"N/A"`

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT a.ID AS ID,  
a.UPRN,p.BuildingNo,
p.Street,p.Postcode ,
a.ItemRef,a.SurveyDate ,
a.OverallRiskCategory ,
a.SurveyorsComments 

INTO  TEMP_' + @tableName + '

FROM TblAsbestos 

AS a JOIN TblProperty 
As p on a.UPRN = p.UPRN
WHERE a.OverallRiskCategory <> ''N/A''
ORDER BY a.OverallRiskCategory'
```